# How to add/delete a section header in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am a new in iPhone,i dont know How can I add a section header in UITableView and 
How can I delete a section header when the row was removed?

Thanks a lot~!

J1.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to read the question posted out here:

[Delete tableview section header view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6140164/delete-tableview-section-header-view)

Should be pretty much what you want to remove a section header

It's in the apple documentation as well:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html